# How to determine if a folder exists and has any files in it in HDFS?

Tags: shell, hadoop

I am writing a shell script and I need to know if a directory does exist and has any files in it in HDFS. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//To check if a HDFS directory exists : 
`enter code here`hdfs dfs -test -e ""
//To check if the size is non-zero
    hdfs dfs -test -e "/*"

Help tools : 
-d: f the path is a directory, return 0.
-e: if the path exists, return 0.
-f: if the path is a file, return 0.
-s: if the path is not empty, return 0.
-z: if the file is zero length, return 0.

Comment: hdfs dfs -test -e "/*". It solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please reformat your answer! i have already done some changes but you revoked my edit.

Answer (score -1):

this seem to be perfect for a shell script

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/49312/hdfs-file-exists-check.html